# remote desktop network failed connection

Tags: windows-xp, windows-vista, remote-desktop

I was trying to create a remote desktop connection from Windows XP to my Windows Vista Ultimate Addition machine at home.  This normally works fine.  Today after my connection was dropped, I tried to reconnect to my machine.  It brings me to the normal startup screen, but when I tried to log in, it gave me the message "This network connection doesn't exist".  This doesn't make much sense, as I have reached a Windows style login screen already.

My connection returned later that day, but I'm curious as to what happened.  Anyone see this before?

Comment: *Edition - "Addition" (line 2) should be "Edition"

Answer (score 0):

The only time I saw something like this was when my network dropped, either due to wireless dropping or me kicking a cable out accidentally.

Comment: I wasn't using wireless, though it could still be a network drop I guess.  But being able to reach a login screen seems to me the connection should be active